# Golang map with any key type and any value type

Tags: go, go-interface, go-map

can i create in golang a map with any key type and any value type ? , something like :

```
dict1 := map[interface]interface{}
```

Thanks a lot  !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [language spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Map_types) for the key type:

> The [comparison operators](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Comparison_operators) == and != must be fully defined for operands
> of the key type;

So most types can be used as a key type, however:

> Slice, map, and function values are not comparable

and thus cannot be used as a map-key.

The value type can be any or (`any` or `interface{}`) type.

```
type mytype struct{}
type ss []string

_ = make(map[interface{}]interface{}) // this works...
_ = make(map[any]any)                 // ... semantically the same
_ = make(map[mytype]any)              // even a struct

_ = make(map[ss]any) // FAILS: invalid map key type ss
```

https://go.dev/play/p/OX_utGp8nfH